# python program way to check for type in Python?

Tags: python

```
def main():
    a,b=numbers(5,1,100)
print("Number of Odd values = " + str(a))
print("Number of Even values = " + str(b))
def numbers(N,A,B):
    even_count,odd_count=0,0
    for i in range(N):
        n=random.randint(A,B)        
        if n%2==0:
            even_count+=1
        else:
            odd_count+=1
    return odd_count, even_count
main()
```

Need fix this code.i don't know when the number can't go through.
print("Number of Odd values = " + str(a))
NameError: name 'a' is not defined

Comment: Hi Cosin, first check out [How to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You should tell us what your expected output is, what you're getting, and what you've tried to solve it.

Comment: it's was stuck of print.can you help me?

Comment: First, names in Python are case-sensitive, so N, A and B are different to n, a and b. Second, the convention is to only use lower-case with underscore, so call them n, a, b. Third, inside `numbers()` you're calling the arguments N,A,B, then assign the function's return value to the tuple a, b in `main()`. Don't call those a,b , call them `odd`, `even` or `x, y` or something that won't lead to severe confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
import random

def numbers(N,A,B):
    even_count,odd_count=0,0
    for i in range(N):
        n=random.randint(A,B)        
        if n%2==0:
            even_count+=1
        else:
            odd_count+=1
    return odd_count, even_count
    
a,b=numbers(5,1,100) 

print("Number of Odd values = " + str(a))
print("Number of Even values = " + str(b))
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to make sure the print statements are coming inside the scope of function main()
and import module random at the top of the script. below is the formatted version.

```
def main():
    a,b=numbers(5,1,100)
    
    print("Number of Odd values = " + str(a))
    print("Number of Even values = " + str(b))


def numbers(N,A,B):
    even_count,odd_count=0,0
    for i in range(N):
        n=random.randint(A,B)        
        if n%2==0:
            even_count+=1
        else:
            odd_count+=1
    return odd_count, even_count
main()
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need you to reorder the code,try this:

```
import random

def numbers(N,A,B):
    even_count, odd_count = 0, 0
    for i in range(N):
        n = random.randint(A, B)
        if n % 2 == 0:
            even_count += 1
        else:
            odd_count += 1
    return odd_count, even_count


def main():
    a, b = numbers(5, 1, 100)
    print("Number of Odd values = " + str(a))
    print("Number of Even values = " + str(b))


main()
```